# Iterating a loop through all objects of a class

Tags: java, object

New to Java-
I'm building a poker program and I've created a player class with some instance variables including "toppair", "highcardst",etc...  I tried to use a placeholder variable to refer to the appropriate player's instance variable rather than relying on if statements.

```
int handsdealt=0;
int straightval=0;
String placeholder="blank";
player playerone = new player("Richard");
player playertwo = new player("Negreanu");
//code omitted
if (handsdealt==1) placeholder="playerone";
else placeholder="playertwo";
//code to determine if hand is a straight -if it is it sets straightval to 1
**if(straightval==1) placeholder.highcardst=straightHigh;**
```

I receive an error on that last line- it looks like java doesn't accept this syntax. Essentially, since this hand is a straight I want to append the value of the "highcardst" instance variable of the "n" th player as n hands have been dealt.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the exact error.

Comment: you can't use variable for object namae

Comment: Seems like you're trying to use JSON in Java code. The closest thing to what you're trying to do is Map.put(...,...);

Comment: _placeholder.highcardst?_ cant be possible as placeholder is a String and I dont think String class has any such member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a list of players and get the instance of the player from the list as required.

```
List<player> players = new ArrayList<player>();
players.add(new player("Richard"));
players.add(new player("Negreanu"));
if(straightval==1) { 
    players.get(handsdealt).highcardst=straightHigh;
}
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Yeah, this approach facilitates a varying number of players - I can deal as many hands as there are elements in the arraylist.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be uses a `String` for your `placeholder` variable where you actually want to refer to a `player` object.

```
player playerone = new player("Richard");
player playertwo = new player("Negreanu");
//code omitted
player placeholder;
if (handsdealt==1) placeholder=playerone;
else placeholder=playertwo;
//code to determine if hand is a straight -if it is it sets straightval to 1
if(straightval==1) placeholder.highcardst=straightHigh;
```

Also, it will make your code easier to follow if you follow normal Java code conventions, such as capitalising the first letter of a class name (e.g. `Player`, not `player`).

Comment: Thank you, I got a notification to initialize the object so my code on line 4 is    [player placeholder = null;]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be in this statement:

```
placeholder.highcardst=straightHigh;
```

You've defined `placeholder` of type `String`, so the property called `highcardst` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(straightval==1) placeholder.highcardst=straightHigh;
```

Error is here. place holder is `String` type not `Player` type. Make temp variable as Player variable and assign

```
Player placeholder;
if (handsdealt==1) placeholder=playerone;
```